Why is my JS event handler not working in SVG?
I am currently making a graphing calculator in C++. I wanted to make multiple versions of said graphing calculator. This first attempt uses SVG and JS to create graphs.
When I create the file and use the SVG file I wish to display the point of the graph (where a user clicks). However, my method to display the coordinates is not working. I click the graph, and nothing happens.
Code:
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

using Function = long double (*)(long double);

double evaluate(Function func, double x) {
    return static_cast<double>(func(x));
}

void plotGraph(Function func, double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY, double stepSize, int SVG_SIZE, const string& hexLineColor) {
    // Calculate number of points to plot
    int numPoints = static_cast<int>((maxX - minX) / stepSize) + 1;

    // Vector to store points
    vector<Point> points(numPoints);

    // Evaluate function at each step and store points
    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
        double x = minX + i * stepSize;
        double y = evaluate(func, x);
        // Check if y is NaN, if so, skip this point
        if (!isnan(y)) {
            points[i] = {x, y};
        } else {
            // Set x-coordinate of the skipped point to NaN so it's not drawn
            points[i] = {NAN, NAN};
        }
    }

    // Normalize points to fit in the specified range
    double xRange = maxX - minX;
    double yRange = maxY - minY;

    for (auto& point : points) {
        if (!std::isnan(point.x)) {
            point.x = (point.x - minX) * SVG_SIZE / xRange;
            point.y = (point.y - minY) * SVG_SIZE / yRange;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the x-position of the y-axis
    double yAxisXPos = -minX * SVG_SIZE / xRange;
    if (minX <= 0 && maxX >= 0) {
        yAxisXPos = -minX / (maxX - minX) * SVG_SIZE;
    } else if (minX > 0) {
        yAxisXPos = 0;
    } else {
        yAxisXPos = SVG_SIZE;
    }

    // Calculate the y-position of the x-axis
    double xAxisYPos;
    if (minY <= 0 && maxY >= 0) {
        xAxisYPos = maxY / (maxY - minY) * SVG_SIZE;
    } else if (minY > 0) {
        xAxisYPos = SVG_SIZE;
    } else {
        xAxisYPos = 0;
    }

    // Open SVG file for writing
    ofstream svgFile("graph.svg");

    // SVG header
    svgFile << "<svg width=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" height=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">" << std::endl;

    // Draw x-axis
    svgFile << "<line x1=\"" << yAxisXPos << "\" y1=\"0\" x2=\"" << yAxisXPos << "\" y2=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" style=\"stroke:black;stroke-width:1\"/>" << std::endl;
    // Draw y-axis
    svgFile << "<line x1=\"0\" y1=\"" << xAxisYPos << "\" x2=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" y2=\"" << xAxisYPos << "\" style=\"stroke:black;stroke-width:1\"/>" << std::endl;

    // Plot points and lines
    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; ++i) {
        // Check if both x-coordinates are not NaN
        if (!isnan(points[i - 1].x) && !isnan(points[i].x)) {
            // Check if both y-coordinates are not NaN
            if (!isnan(points[i - 1].y) && !isnan(points[i].y)) {
                // Draw line between two points
                svgFile << "<line x1=\"" << points[i - 1].x << "\" y1=\"" << SVG_SIZE - points[i - 1].y << "\" "
                        << "x2=\"" << points[i].x << "\" y2=\"" << SVG_SIZE - points[i].y << "\" "
                        << "style=\"stroke:#" << hexLineColor << ";stroke-width:2\"/>" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add event handler for clicking on points
    svgFile << "<script><![CDATA[" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "function showCoordinates(evt) {" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    var svg = evt.target.ownerDocument;" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    point.x = evt.clientX;" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    point.y = evt.clientY;" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    var svgPoint = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    var textElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    textElement.setAttribute('x', svgPoint.x);" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    textElement.setAttribute('y', svgPoint.y);" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    textElement.setAttribute('fill', 'black');" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    textElement.textContent = '(' + svgPoint.x.toFixed(2) + ', ' + svgPoint.y.toFixed(2) + ')';" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "    svg.appendChild(textElement);" << std::endl; // Append to the SVG root
    svgFile << "}" << std::endl;
    svgFile << "]]></script>" << std::endl;

    // Draw a transparent rectangle to capture clicks
    svgFile << "<rect width=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" height=\"" << SVG_SIZE << "\" fill=\"transparent\" onclick=\"showCoordinates(evt)\"/>" << std::endl;

    // Close SVG tag
    svgFile << "</svg>";

    // Close the file
    svgFile.close();

    cout << "Graph created in graph.svg" << endl;
}

I have tried changing the syntax a few times and I have completely changed my approach once (caused an error, so I won't go into detail)

Sorry just an "uneducated guess" but what happens if you try to increase the graphs stroke width to lets say 20px/user units - just for debugging? My assumption is you may have a super tiny hit area as you're creating a bunch of separate line elements – then there are also rounding errors converting screen to svg coordinates. You may also try to create a connected <polyline> or <path> element to slightly enlarge the area responding to pointer events

After some finagling and dinner, it turns out that I was just creating JS script incorrectly in the file. My question is answered, but I'm too new to show it! I did solve the problem, though!

Anyone can answer a question.
